# How to enable always interactive mode for spring-shell command prompt

Tags: spring-shell

My requirement is to execute spring-shell program with `my-command` as a first command then application should prompt again in interactive mode for next command.
Ex:-

```
$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

shell:> prompt-for-next-command
```

but if I execute with my-command:-

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar my-command
```

application getting terminated after executing a single my-command, called  non-interactive mode.

Can we make it always in **interactive** mode even we type first command at run time, so always get `shell:>` prompt for next command execution?
I think these functionalities changed after spring-shell 2.0.x upgrade. previously application was always prompting for next command in interactive mode.